# Plot two ellipses with their respective points

Tags: r, plot

I am developing a function that will generate multiple ellipse plots from linear models and plot their coefficients as points. The objective aim was to plot these points into their respective plots however all the points are plotted onto only one plot.

Here's my script:

```
some_plot_func <- function(data, predictors, type=NULL){
  models <- 
    data %>% 
    keep( ~ all(length(names(.$model)) > 2))

    models <- 
      models %>%
      keep(~all(predictors %in% names(.$model))) 
    
    row_predictor_data <- 
      lapply(models, function(x)
        names(x$model) %>%
          seq_along() %>% as.factor() %>%
          data.frame(id = ., name = as.factor(names(x$model))))
    
    row_predictor_value <-
      lapply(row_predictor_data, function(x)
        which(x == predictors, arr.ind = TRUE)) %>% 
      lapply(., function(x)
        data.frame(x) %>% 
          mutate(pred_num = c('first', 'second')) %>% 
          pivot_wider(names_from = pred_num, values_from = row))
    
    #plot_ellipse <-
    lapply(models, function(x)
      plot(ellipse(x, predictors), type = type))
    
    mapply(function(x, y)points(coef(x)[y$first], coef(x)[y$second]), models, row_predictor_value)
}

#some models
lm1 <- lm(lifespan ~ brain, mammalsleep)
lm2 <- lm(lifespan ~ brain+dream+nondream, mammalsleep)
lm3 <- lm(lifespan ~ brain+sleep, mammalsleep)
lm4 <- lm(lifespan ~ brain+predation+danger+sleep, mammalsleep)
lm5 <- lm(lifespan ~ sleep, mammalsleep)

list_models <- list(lm1, lm2, lm3, lm4, lm5)

#run function
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
some_plot_func(list_models, c('brain', 'sleep'), type='l')
```

The outcome:

[image]

The expected outcome:

There should be one point per plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to have it work by including the following:

```
 mapply(function(x, y)plot(ellipse(x, predictors)) %>% with(points(coef(x)[y$first], coef(x)[y$second], pch=19)), models, row_predictor_value)
```

Rather than:

```
    #plot_ellipse <-
    lapply(models, function(x)
      plot(ellipse(x, predictors), type = type))
    
    mapply(function(x, y)points(coef(x)[y$first], coef(x)[y$second]), models, row_predictor_value)
```

It turns out that you cannot use `pipe` with `points` after `plots` unless you include `with` because it's not considered data.

Results:
[image]

Bonus: If we want to include dashed lines to show the confidence interval region, we can do the following:

```
  mapply(function(x, y)
    plot(ellipse(x, predictors), type = type) %>% 
      with(points(coef(x)[y$first], coef(x)[y$second], pch =19) %>% 
             with(abline(v = confint(x)[y$first,],lty=2)) %>%
             with(abline(h=confint(x)[y$second,],lty=2))),
    models,
    row_predictor_value)
```

[image]

`with` is pretty neat ...